# query string parameter for new method in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, view, query-string

I have a noob's problem,
I have two models "deals" and "companies", a company `has_many` deals.

i want to create a link to `new_deal_path` from `show_company` that pass into query string the id of the company for create a new deal with the company input select with the `company_id` "selected". it works only if the action is "new" in the deal's _form partials but when is edit action, the _form doesn't work for the deal's company_id.

i use simple_form gem this is the snip code from my _form view html

```
  <%= f.input :billed_company,  :selected => params[:billed_company], :collection => Company.all, :value_method => :id, :label_method => :name %>
```

how can avoid this conflict from new method and edit method?

Answer (score 0):

Try using rails `f.collection_select` http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select

If this doesn't solve your problem then there must be some issue with your code / associations etc.